# Who is responsible for ensuring valid documentation on immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, london

My cousin, who holds an OCI card was travelling from London Gatwick to Ahmedabad, India with Emirates Air Line, but she forgot her OCI card at home and somehow she passed through Gatwick and was allowed to travel.

When she reached Ahmedabad, she was denied entry as she is had her British passport, but not a visa or OCI.

**So, I was wondering that who is responsible for immigration check, the airline or any government?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The person traveling is always responsible for having the right paperwork, the airline is not, nor are the immigration officers.

The passport officers at the destination country will check and will usually insist on visa or other proof of being permitted in, like the OCI card, although in most cases the airline will stop a passenger getting on the flight.

Airlines are often charged a fine for allowing people to approach immigration who do not qualify for entry and have to transport those people back or otherwise away, which they will try to get paid for by the passenger.

As pointed out in the comments, in some countries you need to hold an exit visa and it will be the airline and/or the border guards who check you have it, but it is still the responsibility of the person traveling.

Comment: Note that there is a slight caveat here in the case of exit visas. Those are under the purview of the origin country, not the destination country.

Comment: @Flater but still the traveler is the one responsible for having it, not the airline.

Comment: Also to consider: airlines employees cannot known all immigration rules/requirements. They uses an electronic system, but still without all exception listed, and they are not trained to recognize such different documents. "Immigration officers" at exit points also do not known the rules for other countries. And your cousin by having the document knew about the requirement: it is difficult to blame other people. Checklists are important not to have embarrassing situations: recommend your cousins to prepare them.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi agree. I just wanted to know as from destination airport authority person told us to contact to air line for this mistake, by saying that it is air lines responsibility.

Comment: @KinjalPatel It seems likely they are referring to the third paragraph of this answer: "Airlines are often charged a fine for allowing people to approach immigration who do not qualify for entry and have to transport those people back or otherwise away" That is, it isn't that this person is saying it's the airlines responsibility to have the right documents (that's on the passenger), but rather that it's the airline's responsibility to do something about it now (i.e., transport the person back where they came from).

Comment: @jwenting: I read OP's question as "blaming" the airport for not stopping them before they got on the flight - not for the actual lack of documentation itself. Note that the question is _"who is responsible for immigration check, the airline or any government?"_, where I infer that "airline" implies the expectation that they do pre-flight checks of passengers' documentation.

Comment: @Flater: I suppose you mean the airline and not: as "blaming" the airport.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: I conflated airline and airport in my comment, apologies.

Comment: @Flater the airport and/or airline often act as an agent of the government in this, at least in part. E.g. at Amsterdam the check in agent does a screening of your documents, then an airport employee does one before you enter the customs/border patrol queue (mostly to ensure you are getting into the correct line though), then you go through passport control (if it's not a Schengen line) by government agents, then there may be a customs check by government agents co-located with the airport employees performing the security check (or if they call in customs or police on noticing something).